# Why is such a big excerpt being returned for Solr search query?

Tags: solr, highlight

I am trying to determine why the highlighted excerpt is so large and if there's a way to reduce it.

Consider the following:

- Solr version **5.5.5**
- My schema for text field looks like:

  ```
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
      -->
      <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal. -->
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
              ignoreCase="true"
              words="stopwords.txt"
              />
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
              protected="protwords.txt"
              generateWordParts="1"
              generateNumberParts="1"
              catenateWords="1"
              catenateNumbers="1"
              catenateAll="0"
              splitOnCaseChange="0"
              preserveOriginal="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="18"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
              ignoreCase="true"
              words="stopwords.txt"
              />
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
              protected="protwords.txt"
              generateWordParts="1"
              generateNumberParts="1"
              catenateWords="0"
              catenateNumbers="0"
              catenateAll="0"
              splitOnCaseChange="0"
              preserveOriginal="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="multiterm">
      <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
              ignoreCase="true"
              words="stopwords.txt"
              />
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
              protected="protwords.txt"
              generateWordParts="1"
              generateNumberParts="1"
              catenateWords="0"
              catenateNumbers="0"
              catenateAll="0"
              splitOnCaseChange="1"
              preserveOriginal="1"/>
      <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  ```
- Highlight Component for Solr has the following configuration:

  ```
  <searchComponent class="solr.HighlightComponent" name="highlight">
    <highlighting>
      <!-- Configure the standard fragmenter -->
      <!-- This could most likely be commented out in the "default" case -->
      <fragmenter name="gap"
                  default="true"
                  class="solr.highlight.GapFragmenter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <int name="hl.fragsize">30</int>
        </lst>
      </fragmenter>

      <!-- A regular-expression-based fragmenter
           (for sentence extraction)
        -->
      <fragmenter name="regex"
                  class="solr.highlight.RegexFragmenter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <!-- slightly smaller fragsizes work better because of slop -->
          <int name="hl.fragsize">30</int>
          <!-- allow 50% slop on fragment sizes -->
          <float name="hl.regex.slop">0.5</float>
          <!-- a basic sentence pattern -->
          <str name="hl.regex.pattern">[-\w ,/\n\&quot;&apos;]{20,200}</str>
        </lst>
      </fragmenter>

      <!-- Configure the standard formatter -->
      <formatter name="html"
                 default="true"
                 class="solr.highlight.HtmlFormatter">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.simple.pre"><![CDATA[<strong>]]></str>
          <str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[</strong>]]></str>
        </lst>
      </formatter>
      <!-- Configure the standard fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="simple"
                       default="true"
                       class="solr.highlight.SimpleFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- Configure the single fragListBuilder -->
      <fragListBuilder name="single"
                       class="solr.highlight.SingleFragListBuilder"/>

      <!-- default tag FragmentsBuilder -->
      <fragmentsBuilder name="default"
                        default="true"
                        class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
        <!--
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.multiValuedSeparatorChar">/</str>
        </lst>
        -->
      </fragmentsBuilder>

      <!-- multi-colored tag FragmentsBuilder -->
      <fragmentsBuilder name="colored"
                        class="solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.tag.pre"><![CDATA[
               <b style="background:yellow">,<b style="background:lawgreen">,
               <b style="background:aquamarine">,<b style="background:magenta">,
               <b style="background:palegreen">,<b style="background:coral">,
               <b style="background:wheat">,<b style="background:khaki">,
               <b style="background:lime">,<b style="background:deepskyblue">]]></str>
          <str name="hl.tag.post"><![CDATA[</b>]]></str>
        </lst>
      </fragmentsBuilder>

      <boundaryScanner name="default"
                       default="true"
                       class="solr.highlight.SimpleBoundaryScanner">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <str name="hl.bs.maxScan">10</str>
          <str name="hl.bs.chars">.,!? &#9;&#10;&#13;</str>
        </lst>
      </boundaryScanner>

      <boundaryScanner name="breakIterator"
                       class="solr.highlight.BreakIteratorBoundaryScanner">
        <lst name="defaults">
          <!-- type should be one of CHARACTER, WORD(default), LINE and SENTENCE -->
          <str name="hl.bs.type">WORD</str>
          <!-- language and country are used when constructing Locale object.  -->
          <!-- And the Locale object will be used when getting instance of BreakIterator -->
          <str name="hl.bs.language">en</str>
          <str name="hl.bs.country">US</str>
        </lst>
      </boundaryScanner>
    </highlighting>
  </searchComponent>
  ```
- The query I perform is:

  ```
  GET /solr/al_test/select?fl=item_id%2Cindex_id%2Cscore&qf=tm_body%24summary%5E8.0&qf=tm_body%24value%5E3.0&qf=tm_title%5E21.0&start=0&rows=30&sort=score%20desc&hl=true&hl.fl=content&hl.simple.pre=%5BHIGHLIGHT%5D&hl.simple.post=%5B%2FHIGHLIGHT%5D&hl.snippets=3&hl.fragsize=55&hl.mergeContiguous=true&wt=json&json.nl=map&q=%22Jan%22%20AND%20%22Jedli%C4%8Dka%22
  ```
- The response is:

  ```
  {
    "response": {
      "numFound": 1,
      "start": 0,
      "maxScore": 8.571791,
      "docs": [
        {
          "index_id": "al_global_search_nodes",
          "item_id": "6459",
          "score": 8.571791
        }
      ]
    },
    "highlighting": {
      "9qe7lo-al_global_search_nodes-6459": {
        "content": [
          "<p>Die Auseinandersetzung mit dem Thema der Landschaft spielt im Werk von [HIGHLIGHT]Jan[/HIGHLIGHT] [HIGHLIGHT]Jedlička[/HIGHLIGHT] (*1944, Prag) seit Ende der",
          " Licht, Schatten.<br />Jedlička sammelt in der Maremma (wie auch in Irland oder der Prager Umgebung) Erde und Gestein, um daraus im Atelier Pigmente herzustellen, die er auf einer mit Japanpapier beschichteten Leinwand in freien Formen sedimentieren lässt. Schwer fassbare Elemente wie das reflektierte Licht auf dem Wasser bedürfen der technischen Transformation durch die Kamera oder die Mittel der Druckgrafik (Heliogravur und Mezzotinto). Die Basis für ein Sujet in Photosiebdruck war gar das handfeste Eingreifen des Künstlers in die Landschaft. Mit einem verschmitzten Lächeln erzählt er, wie er eines Tages nach einer langen Trockenperiode eine Schleuse öffnete und das Wasser in die aufgesprungene Lehmkruste fliessen liess. Die Kreise, die sich am zweiten Tag zufällig gebildet hatten, hat er dann fotografiert und für die Siebdrucke verwendet. Die Mezzotinten dagegen sind von Hand in einem langwierigen trockenen Verfahren hergestellt. Auf den aufgerauten Kupferplatten wird das Licht mit einem Polierstahl geduldig und minutiös herausgearbeitet, ‹entwickelt› wie Jedlička es nennt.<br />Die körperliche Anstrengung bei all diesen Arbeitsprozessen - Farbenherstellung, Plattenvorbereitung, lange Streifzüge mit der Kamera - nimmt Jedlička gerne in Kauf. Die Resultate aus den langwierigen Verfahren sind oft erstaunlich: die Strahlkraft der Pigmente, das tiefe Schwarz der Mezzotinten und Heliogravuren, das vielschichtige Grau auf der Leinwand.<br />Jedlička ist fasziniert vom steten Wandel der Phänomene, die sich in jedem Moment neu entfalten. Das Hinterfragen der sichtbaren Oberfläche der Wirklichkeit ist bei ihm tief eingegraben. So werden die achtsamen Bewegungen im Landschaftsraum, das genaue Festhalten der Dinge und ihre mediale Verwandlung elementare Bausteine seiner Kunst, die uns stets von neuem in Bann ziehen.</p>\n\n\nSibylle\n\nJan\n\nJan Jedlička"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- The source text has the next value:

  ```
  <p>Die Auseinandersetzung mit dem Thema der Landschaft spielt im Werk von Jan Jedlička (*1944, Prag) seit Ende der Siebzigerjahre eine zentrale Rolle. Sein künstlerisches Schaffen nährt sich dabei besonders von der Maremma, jener halb von Menschen geschaffenen Küstenlandschaft in der südlichen Toskana. Die Elemente der Landschaft sind geprägt durch die Urbanisierungsarbeiten früherer Jahrhunderte, als in den Sümpfen zwischen Land und Meer Entwässerungskanäle und Dämme angelegt wurden&nbsp;- einige funktionieren bis heute, andere wurden aufgegeben.<br />Es geht dem Künstler aber auch um eine geistige Dimension dieses Landstrichs: Wie sich im Laufe der Geschichte Mensch und Landschaft miteinander entwickelt haben und wie sich diese Vergangenheit in das heutige Angesicht der Landschaft eingeschrieben hat.<br />In der Tat ist die langjährige Beschäftigung mit immer demselben Landstrich ein Nachsinnen über dessen Phänomene, Farben und Lichtverhältnisse; ein langsames, fast körperliches Suchen nach Natur, Licht, Schatten.<br />Jedlička sammelt in der Maremma (wie auch in Irland oder der Prager Umgebung) Erde und Gestein, um daraus im Atelier Pigmente herzustellen, die er auf einer mit Japanpapier beschichteten Leinwand in freien Formen sedimentieren lässt. Schwer fassbare Elemente wie das reflektierte Licht auf dem Wasser bedürfen der technischen Transformation durch die Kamera oder die Mittel der Druckgrafik (Heliogravur und Mezzotinto). Die Basis für ein Sujet in Photosiebdruck war gar das handfeste Eingreifen des Künstlers in die Landschaft. Mit einem verschmitzten Lächeln erzählt er, wie er eines Tages nach einer langen Trockenperiode eine Schleuse öffnete und das Wasser in die aufgesprungene Lehmkruste fliessen liess. Die Kreise, die sich am zweiten Tag zufällig gebildet hatten, hat er dann fotografiert und für die Siebdrucke verwendet. Die Mezzotinten dagegen sind von Hand in einem langwierigen trockenen Verfahren hergestellt. Auf den aufgerauten Kupferplatten wird das Licht mit einem Polierstahl geduldig und minutiös herausgearbeitet, &lsaquo;entwickelt&rsaquo; wie Jedlička es nennt.<br />Die körperliche Anstrengung bei all diesen Arbeitsprozessen&nbsp;- Farbenherstellung, Plattenvorbereitung, lange Streifzüge mit der Kamera&nbsp;- nimmt Jedlička gerne in Kauf. Die Resultate aus den langwierigen Verfahren sind oft erstaunlich: die Strahlkraft der Pigmente, das tiefe Schwarz der Mezzotinten und Heliogravuren, das vielschichtige Grau auf der Leinwand.<br />Jedlička ist fasziniert vom steten Wandel der Phänomene, die sich in jedem Moment neu entfalten. Das Hinterfragen der sichtbaren Oberfläche der Wirklichkeit ist bei ihm tief eingegraben. So werden die achtsamen Bewegungen im Landschaftsraum, das genaue Festhalten der Dinge und ihre mediale Verwandlung elementare Bausteine seiner Kunst, die uns stets von neuem in Bann ziehen.</p>
  ```

As you can see, the response has second snippet pretty much exceeding the fragsize limit (as far as I understand, because I'm not that familiar with Solr).

I've read documentation regarding 
`<fragmenter name="regex" class="solr.highlight.RegexFragmenter">` and tried tweaking the fragsize but that didn't yield any results.

Also I read about `<filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="18"/>` and reduced the `maxGamSize` from 50 to 18, but i think it can affect the search, so that doesn't sound like a great idea to me.

I have also tried to use `debugQuery` option, but that only explains me why the given item is being returned.

How can I reduce the excerpt length or maybe tell me how can i debug the excerpt being built?

### Update

After i set `hl.mergeContiguous` parameter to `false` the actual excerpt is not changed that much.

```
{
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "maxScore": 8.57209,
    "docs": [
      {
        "index_id": "al_global_search_nodes",
        "item_id": "6459",
        "score": 8.57209
      }
    ]
  },
  "highlighting": {
    "9qe7lo-al_global_search_nodes-6459": {
      "content": [
        " spielt im Werk von [HIGHLIGHT]Jan[/HIGHLIGHT] [HIGHLIGHT]Jedlička[/HIGHLIGHT] (*1944, Prag) seit Ende der",
        " Licht, Schatten.<br />Jedlička sammelt in der Maremma (wie auch in Irland oder der Prager Umgebung) Erde und Gestein, um daraus im Atelier Pigmente herzustellen, die er auf einer mit Japanpapier beschichteten Leinwand in freien Formen sedimentieren lässt. Schwer fassbare Elemente wie das reflektierte Licht auf dem Wasser bedürfen der technischen Transformation durch die Kamera oder die Mittel der Druckgrafik (Heliogravur und Mezzotinto). Die Basis für ein Sujet in Photosiebdruck war gar das handfeste Eingreifen des Künstlers in die Landschaft. Mit einem verschmitzten Lächeln erzählt er, wie er eines Tages nach einer langen Trockenperiode eine Schleuse öffnete und das Wasser in die aufgesprungene Lehmkruste fliessen liess. Die Kreise, die sich am zweiten Tag zufällig gebildet hatten, hat er dann fotografiert und für die Siebdrucke verwendet. Die Mezzotinten dagegen sind von Hand in einem langwierigen trockenen Verfahren hergestellt. Auf den aufgerauten Kupferplatten wird das Licht mit einem Polierstahl geduldig und minutiös herausgearbeitet, ‹entwickelt› wie Jedlička es nennt.<br />Die körperliche Anstrengung bei all diesen Arbeitsprozessen - Farbenherstellung, Plattenvorbereitung, lange Streifzüge mit der Kamera - nimmt Jedlička gerne in Kauf. Die Resultate aus den langwierigen Verfahren sind oft erstaunlich: die Strahlkraft der Pigmente, das tiefe Schwarz der Mezzotinten und Heliogravuren, das vielschichtige Grau auf der Leinwand.<br />Jedlička ist fasziniert vom steten Wandel der Phänomene, die sich in jedem Moment neu entfalten. Das Hinterfragen der sichtbaren Oberfläche der Wirklichkeit ist bei ihm tief eingegraben. So werden die achtsamen Bewegungen im Landschaftsraum, das genaue Festhalten der Dinge und ihre mediale Verwandlung elementare Bausteine seiner Kunst, die uns stets von neuem in Bann ziehen.</p>\n\n\nSibylle\n\nJan\n\nJan Jedlička"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing your query is `Jedlička` since that's what highlighted in your first query. You also have `hl.mergeContiguous` set, which means that (as far as I understand) multiple fragments will be merged into one. In your long field, the term `Jedlička` appears often - which I guess mean that you end up with one, large, merged text. Not sure why it doesn't tag the terms, but I'd try to at least start with `hl.mergeContiguous` disabled.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks for your idea, i have tried it. Unfortunately, it did not help for some reason